# Visual studio 2010 installation to use silverlight application

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, silverlight

I have to learn working on Silver light application of VS2010. I have never used Visual Studio before. When I try to [install VS 2010 from this location](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23691). It gives an error that "Setup has detected that this computer doen't meet the requirement to install this software The following blocking issues must be resolved before you can install Microsoft VS2010 service pack 1." and inside the menu I have

> Installation Requirements:
>
> A compatible version of Visual Studio 2010 was not detected on the system. This update is designed for only the Microsoft Visual Studio 2010.

I have installed nothing prior to this VS 2010 installation unsuccessful try.

Could any one please answer following questions ?

1. What should i install prior to this vs 2010 installation ?
2. Currently i have checked in "Uninstall a program of `Window 7`" I have nothing installed like SDKs etc.I even don't what is it used for ?Why do we need it ?
3. Actually if VS 2010 is installed successfully then i have to work on silver light using c# and xaml. Could anyone please suggest me appropriate version installation according to my work ? 
   Thanks in advance foe all this help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The download link you've downloaded is only the service pack, not the full product. You first need to download Visual Studio 2010 RTM. You either need to download Visual Studio Professional from MSDN Subscriptions (or install it from media) or use the [Visual Web Developer 2010 Express](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads#d-2010-express) edition, then [install Service Pack 1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23691) and the [Silverlight Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=28358).

I hope you are aware that Silverlight is a Deprecated technology and will not be further invested in in future version of Visual Studio.

Comment: there are so many options on this links http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads#d-2010-express (for c++,c#, VB etc), I have to use c# and Xaml (silverlight) so what should i install from there ?

Comment: Actually i am installing c# among all the options (Am i going right?)

Comment: it persist the error on the last installation you suggested (The first two Visual studio 2010 express (c#) and Install Service Pack1 installed finely but Silvertools gives error that:) "Setup has detected that this computer doesn't meet the requirement to install this software The following blocking issues must be resolved before you can install Microsoft silverlight 5 Tools for Visual studio 2010 SP1 software update" and below it gives : "Installation Requirements:

The Visual Web Developer feature for Visual Studio 2010 SP1 must be installed before installation can continue.
"

Comment: What would you suggest me in this situation ? Thanks for all your help

Comment: Did you install the Web Edition? it seems to depend on that. After installing the web edition, reapply SP1.

Comment: and do i need to unistall c# edition ? before that ?

Comment: That worked fine I have installed after c# and it works, Thanks for this big help